# addThis buttons do not show

Tags: addthis

I am using the default code. Why don't my buttons show up? Do I need to have the images locally? need absolute path?

```
<!-- AddThis Follow BEGIN -->

<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_follow" addthis:userid="myclient"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_twitter_follow" addthis:userid="myclient"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_pinterest_follow" addthis:userid="myclient"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-510e973014b90fdf"></script>
<!-- AddThis Follow END -->
```

Comment: I forgot I was using DoNotTrackMe plugin for Firefox and AddThis widget stopped to appear. Please, also check browser plugins don't interfere.

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need the images to be stored locally.
2. You don't need an absolute path

Have you checked if the js is loading properly? You can do that in chrome (developer tools) or firefox (firebug) and check if it is able to get the script loading with no errors.